# Using DbContext.SaveChanges() with "After insert trigger"

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

My after insert trigger raises an exception when calling `dbContext.SaveChanges()` of Entity Framework.

Error message:

> The member with identity '' does not exist in the metadata collection

This is my trigger code:

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AddAccountForCustomer] 
ON [dbo].[Customer] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Acc_Accounts'))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @customerName nvarchar(256) = (SELECT NameAr FROM inserted)
        DECLARE @customerID bigint = (SELECT customerID FROM inserted)

        DECLARE @serial NCHAR(10) = (
            SELECT 
                '11' + 
                RIGHT(
                    '00000000' + CAST(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(AccountID, '11', '') AS bigint)) + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)), 
                    8)
            FROM [Acc_Accounts] 
            WHERE '11' = LEFT(AccountID, 2));
            
        SELECT @serial

        INSERT INTO Acc_Accounts (AccountID, [Name], AccountTypeID, ParentAccountID) values 
            (
                (CASE WHEN @serial IS NULL THEN ('1100000001') ELSE @serial END),
                @customerName, '1000000000', '1100000000'
            );

        UPDATE [Customer] 
        SET AccountID = 
            (CASE WHEN @serial IS NULL 
                THEN ('1100000001') 
                ELSE @serial 
            END) 
        WHERE CustomerID = @customerID;
    END
END
```

And this is the insert operation in C# code:

```csharp
private static void Add(CustomerDTO Customer)
{
    try
    {
        using (Entities context = new Entities())
        {
            var data = Mapper.Map<CustomerDTO, Customer>(Customer);
            context.Customers.Add(data);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

There was a solution for same issue in stackoverflow, but with removing the trigger, is there any solution without removing the trigger??

Comment: That trigger is pretty messed up.  Why are you checking for the existence of a table in your database?  Don't you know whether or not it exists?  Also that trigger assumes only one row was inserted, so it will blow up if you try to insert more.  And you should always SET NOCOUNT ON at the beginning of a trigger.  Once you fix it, the error might go away.

Comment: I have already used SET NOCOUNT ON and removed checking for table existense and nothing is happen...Why this tigger is "pretty messed up"?? @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand about writing (after) triggers is that you nearly always need to put `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning of them.  Otherwise, the action of the trigger might update, insert, or delete rows, and that will be returned as part of the rowcount which will cause your app code to think something's wrong.

The second thing is that you've written a single-row trigger. You are assuming that only one row will be affected when the trigger fires. This isn't the case. You need to assume that you're writing triggers where inserted and/or deleted contain multiple rows.

Third, you aren't allowed to `SELECT` data within a trigger any more, unless you turn on an option that you shouldn't.

Fourth, don't use the information schema views any more. Use the appropriate system views i.e. `sys.tables`.

I've reworked the skeleton of the code that you need. You've lost me a bit on the serial stuff. I presume there's an expression or lookup needed where I put the `??` part. But this should be enough to get you started.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TR_dbo_Customer_AddAccountForCustomer
ON dbo.Customer 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables AS t 
                        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
                        ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id 
                        WHERE s.[name] = N'dbo'
                        AND t.[name] = N'Acc_Accounts')
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO dbo.Acc_Accounts 
            (AccountID, [Name], AccountTypeID, ParentAccountID)
        SELECT 
            ??, 
            i.NameAr, 
            1000000000, 
            1100000000
        -- (SELECT '11' + RIGHT('00000000'+ CAST(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(AccountID, '11', '') AS bigint)) + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)), 8)
        -- FROM [Acc_Accounts] WHERE '11' = LEFT(AccountID,2));
        -- ((case when @serial is null then ('1100000001') else @serial end), 
        FROM inserted AS i;

        UPDATE c 
        SET c.AccountID = 
            CASE WHEN ??? IS NULL 
                THEN '1100000001'
                ELSE ??? 
            END 
        FROM dbo.Customers AS c
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
        ON i.customerID = c.CustomerID;
    END;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you @Greg Low...the issue was in line: "select @serial", i was select variable to test returned value and forget to comment it before executing the trigger

Comment: Great to hear. Don't ignore the other points though. In particular, you need to make sure it isn't a one-row trigger like you had. Test it with a multi-row INSERT.